# How do I wrap a page element with a dynamically generated element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have the following code

```
var input = $('#el_id');
wrapper = $(document.createElement('div'));
wrapper.addClass('small');
wrapper.css('width',200);
input.wrap(wrapper);

alert(input.children().length)
```

I get 0 for the children length.  What I want is:

```
<div class="small" style="width: 200px;">
     <input type="text" id="el_id" />
</div>
```

But I want the small div to be dynamically generated.  Any idea why this isn't working?

**UPDATE**

It turns out my issue lies on another line of code.  I want to assign the wrapper to a variable after I wrap and:

```
block = input.wrap("<div class='"+container_class+"' style='width: "+wrap_width+"px;'></div>");
```

does not work.  It returns the input which makes sense.  But how can I return the wrapper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are doing it right.

You just need to save the results of the wrap function to a variable:

**Edit:**  Updated the code to get parent():

```
var wrapped = input.wrap(wrapper).parent();
alert(wrapped.children().length);
```

Comment: the thing screwing me up is "wrapped" in your example is not returning the same results as if i were to just grab the wrapper element with $('#wrapper_id').  do you know why that is?

Comment: Whoops - I thought wrap() returned the new context - sorry about that.  You COULD just do: input.wrap("..."); var wrapped = input.parent();

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap#elem), it appears that wrap() only accepts a DOM element or a string.  You are passing it a jQuery object, which may not work.  I'd try this:

```
$('#el_id').wrap('<div class="small" style="width: 200px;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You are trying to wrap with a jquery object and not a dom object which is what the wrap() function expects.